# The torsion subgroup of principal units $U^{(1)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, local-field

$\newcommand{\U}{U^{(1)}}$
$\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$
$\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\char}{char}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$

I have a question about the torsion subgroup of principal units $\U$.

Let $K$ be a local field with valuation ring $\O$, maximal ideal $\p$.
Let $q = p^f = \#\O/\p$. Let $\char K = 0$. The group of principal units $\U$ is
$$
\U := 1 + \p.
$$
For $n \in \N$, let $\mu_n$ be a group of $n$-th roots of unity,
i.e.
$$
  \mu_n := \{ x \in K \mid x^n = 1 \}.
$$
Then, I want to show that:

> The torsion subgroup of $\U$ can be written as $\mu_{p^a}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

First, I tried to show that for any $x \in \U$ which has finite order,
an order of $x$ can be written as $p^n$ for some $n \in \N$,
but I failed.

This question is related to the Proposition (5.7) in
Neukirch, "*Algebraic Number Theory*" at page 140.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $U^1$ is a $Z_p$-module of finite type (*), the general theory of modules over principal domains shows that its torsion subgroup is finite, hence cyclic because we are inside the multiplicative group of a field.

(*) Quickest proof: filter $U^1$ by the subgroups $U^n$ = $1$ + $P^n$ . It is easily shown that $U^n$/$U^{n+1}$ is isomorphic to $P^n$/$P^{n+1}$ (non canonically isomorphic to the additive group of the residue field ). Since $U^1$ = projective limit of the quotients $U^1$/$U^n$ , we are done . This even shows that the $Z_p$-rank of $U^1$ is equal to the degree of the field over $Q_p$ .

Comment: I understood the torsion subgroup is cyclic and finite, but why the order is p-th power ?

Comment: The torsion subgroup is a finite  Zp-module, hence a finite p-group

Comment: Sorry, but why finite Zp-module is p group? Regarding finite Z-mod is not necessarily p group I believe, because there can be other prime elements which devices the order.

Comment: A Z-module is not necessarily a Zp-module.

Comment: Of course I understand that, but how do you explain finite Zp-module is p-group,not like finite Z-module ?

Comment: Suppose that (A, +) is a finite abelian group of order a prime to p. If A were a Zp-module, it would be killed by the invertible element a, hence A would be null.

Comment: It can also be shown directly: if $M$ is a finite $Z_p$-module, then the action of $Z_p$ factors through some a finite quotient $Z_p/nZ_p$. But if $n=p^ab$ with $(b,p)=1$, then $nZ_p=p^aZ_p$ so $Z_p/nZ_p=Z_p/p^aZ_p=Z/p^aZ$ and thus $M$ is a finite $Z/p^aZ$ module. From here The result is straightforward

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $1+x$ is a torsion element of $U^{(1)}$, $x \in \mathfrak p$, killed by $z \in \mathbb Z_p$. That is, $(1+x)^z=1$. If $z=p^au$, $u \in \mathbb Z_p^{\times}$. Let $uv=1$, $v \in \mathbb Z_p^\times$.
$$(1+x)^{{p^a}u}=1 \implies (1+x)^{{p^a}uv}=(1+x)^{p^a}=1 \implies 1+x \in \mu_{p^a}.$$