# Free submodule of finite index over pid

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I am reading Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory and I am currently stuck on the proof of Proposition 5.7 on page 140.

Neukirch introduces the $Z_p$ module $U^{(n)} = 1 + P^n$, where $P$ is the unique maximal ideal of the ring of integers $o$ of the complete local field $K$.

The $Z_p$ action on the multiplicative group $U^{(n)}$ is defined as follows.

For $1+x\in U^{(n)}, z\in Z_p$, one has $z(x) = (1+x)^z$.

Neukirch claims that the torsion subgroup of the $Z_p$-module $U^{(1)}$ is the set of roots of unity of order powers of $p$. I.e., elements $1+x\in U^{(1)} = 1 + P$, such that $(1+x)^{m} = 1$ for some $m=p^a$ for some natural number $a$. I don't understand why $m$ must be a power of $p$. Also, if we take $U^{(1)}$'s quotient with its torsion subgroup, then we ought to get a free module. Neukirch claims that this module is $U^{(n)}$, why is that?

I do agree that since $U^{(1)}$ has $U^{(n)}$ as a submodule of finite index that we may write $U^{(1)} = U^{(n)} + (U^{(1)}/U^{(n)})$, but why should $U^{(1)}/U^{(n)}$ be isomorphic to the roots of unity of order power of $p$? I have no idea, any light shed on this matter would be highly regarded.

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Comment: $1+P$ is a $Z$ module and for all $c \in 1+P$, $\lim_{k \to \infty} c^{p^k} = 1$ thus it is a $Z_p$ module. If $c$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity $\lim_{k \to \infty} c^{p^k} =1$ implies $m = p^a$ for some $a$. Also $1+pO_K$ is torsion free thus $U^{(n)}$ is torsion free for $n$ the valuation of $p$. I think the isomorphism between $U^{(1)}_{tors}$ and $U^{(1)}/U^{(n)}$ can be obtained from cardinality but there is probably a better way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on why is $1+pO_K$ torsion free? I think its torsion should be exactly the roots of unity. Anothet question is why is the quotient of U1 by Un gives the torsion group?

Answer (score 2):

As regards the first question (why must $m$ be a power of $p$), this has been asked and answered in [MS/1697097](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1697097/96384). As soon as you believe that $U^{(1)}$ is a $\mathbb Z_p$-module, it is clear that every torsion element is of $p$-power order, and then you remember that roots of unity are cyclic (and a local field cannot contain infinitely many roots of unity; or, if you even believe that $U^{(1)}$ is a *finitely generated* $\mathbb Z_p$-module, you know the entire torsion will be killed by some $p$-power, you can conclude from there with cyclicity that it must be exactly the group of $p^a$-th roots for some natural $a$).

Then,

> if we take $U^{(1)}$'s quotient with its torsion subgroup, then we ought to
>   get a free module. Neukirch claims that this module is $U^{(n)}$, why is
>   that?

I do not have the book at hand, but I doubt that that is what Neukirch claims, because it is wrong in general, see counterexample at the end. What is true is that for high enough $n$, $U^{(n)}$ is *isomorphic* to $U^{(1)}/U^{(1)}_{tors}$ as $\mathbb Z_p$-module, namely, they are both free of rank $r = [K:\mathbb Q_p]$ (resp. $[K:\mathbb F_p((t))]$ if we are in positive characteristic).

This is shown via filtrations of $U^{(1)}$ with the $U^{(n)}$, see also link above;  certainly this is also done by Neukirch, there is a good treatment in Serre's *Local Fields*, and freely available on the internet is [this book by Fesenko and Vostokov](https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/plp/pmzibf/book/vol.pdf), where it is done in sections 1.5. and 1.6 (pp.12 to 22). The upshot is that for each $n$, there are isomorphisms

$U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)} \simeq (k = o/P, +)$ (additive group of the residue field)

and for $n > e/(p-1)$, where $e$ is the ramification index (i.e. $(P^e) = (p)$ in $o$), raising to the $p$-th power induces an isomorphism $U^{(n)} \stackrel{\simeq}\rightarrow U^{(n+e)}$.

Now if $f$ is the inertia degree, i.e. the order of the residue field $k$ is $p^f$, this shows that for $n > e/(p-1)$, $U^{(n)}$ is a free $\mathbb Z_p$-module of rank $ef =r$. Further, since $U^{(1)}/U^{(n)}$ is finite (of order $p^{fn}$), from the structure theory of finitely generated modules (and the fact that $\mathbb Z_p$ is infinite) it follows that the free part of $U^{(1)}$ must have the same rank, i.e. be *isomorphic* to those $U^{(n)}$. Then it follows further from that structure theory that

$U^{(1)} \simeq U^{(1)}_{tors} \times \mathbb Z_p^r$, and of course the torsion part is $\simeq \mathbb Z_p/p^a \simeq \mathbb Z/p^a$.

So *abstractly*, there is an isomorphism $U^{(1)} \simeq U^{(1)}_{tors} \times U^{(n)}$ for all higher $n$, but it can happen that this iso is not given by the natural inclusion $U^{(n)} \subset U^{(1)}$ (for any $n$).

---

Finally, to see this, i.e. it is *not necessarily true* that some $U^{(n)}$ *itself* works as a complement to  $U^{(1)}_{tors}$ in $U^{(1)}$, look at the following counterexample: Let $p = 3$, take the unique unramified quadratic extension $F \vert \mathbb Q_3$, and let $K=F(\mu_3)$, this is the field whose principal units we consider. For $K\vert \mathbb Q_3$, we have $e=f=2, r=4$. Then there is an isomorphism of $\mathbb Z_p$-modules

$U^{(1)} \simeq \mathbb Z_3/3  \oplus \mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_3$

which obviously identifies the $3$rd roots of unity with the first factor $\mathbb Z_3/3 \simeq \mathbb Z/3$; but the filtration looks like this:

$U^{(2)} \simeq 0 \oplus 3\mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_3$

$U^{(3)} \simeq 0 \oplus 3\mathbb Z_3 \oplus 3\mathbb Z_3 \oplus 3\mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_3$

$U^{(4)} \simeq 0 \oplus 9\mathbb Z_3 \oplus 3\mathbb Z_3 \oplus 3\mathbb Z_3 \oplus 3\mathbb Z_3$

$U^{(5)} \simeq 0 \oplus 9\mathbb Z_3 \oplus 9\mathbb Z_3 \oplus 9\mathbb Z_3 \oplus 3\mathbb Z_3$

etc. Note that all $U^{(n\ge 2)}$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb Z_p$-modules (namely, free of rank $4$), each $U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)}$ is isomorphic to the additive group of the residue field $\mathbb F_{3^2}$, and multiplication with $p$ gives isos $U^{(n)} \simeq U^{(n+2)}$ for all $n \ge 2$ (but not for $n=1 = e/(p-1)$); but also note that $U^{(1)}/U^{(n)}$ is never isomorphic to the torsion part.